# Ошибка CS0507 'B.Variable": невозможно изменить модификаторы доступа при переопределении "protected", унаследованном из "A.Variable"

Tags: c#

Есть такой код:

```
class A
{
    protected virtual int Variable { get; private set; }
}

class B : A
{
    public override int Variable { get; private set; }
}
```

Почему возникает ошибка: "Ошибка    CS0507  'B.Variable": невозможно изменить модификаторы доступа при переопределении "protected", унаследованном из "A.Variable"."???

Comment: А что вы пытаетесь сделать, поменяв protected на public? Фактически, это уже разные свойства, потому что первое - свойство класса и только его, а второе - общедоступное.

Comment: @Monk Но мне надо чтобы оно было публичным!

Comment: Чтобы оно стало публичным именно в B? Не можете сделать его публичным в A?

Comment: если хотите сделать публичным используйте перекрытие в котором устанавливается и возвращается базовое поле.